# Error inflating class fragment Android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**Error**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.pockethcm.greytrix.test, PID: 6566
                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #29: Duplicate id 0x7f09012d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3680)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
                          at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:557)
                          at com.pockethcm.greytrix.test.Fragments.DashboardFragment.openPunchDetailDialog(DashboardFragment.kt:1183)
                          at com.pockethcm.greytrix.test.Fragments.DashboardFragment$sendLocationData$1.onSuccess(DashboardFragment.kt:767)
                          at com.pockethcm.greytrix.test.Fragments.DashboardFragment$sendLocationData$1.onSuccess(DashboardFragment.kt:102)
                          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:27)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

**Fragment Code**

```
  var mapFragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
    if(mapFragment != null){
        mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback {
            googleMap = it
            val location1 = LatLng(13.03,77.60)
            val location2 = LatLng(13.53,77.67)
            googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location1).title("First Location"))
            googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location2).title("Second Location"))

            val center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location1)
            val zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15f)
            val markerPoints = LatLngBounds(
                    location1, location2)
            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(markerPoints,30))
            })
        })
    }
```

**punchdetailLayout**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
   />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Address"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              >
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Locality"
                  android:layout_weight="0.5"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  />
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/locality"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:layout_weight="0.5"
                  />
          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              >
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Time"
                  android:layout_weight="0.5"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  />
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/time"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:layout_weight="0.5"
                  />
          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              >
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/ok"
                  android:text="OK">
              </Button>
          </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Records Found!"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/no_rec"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Post the **full** stacktrace and the code that is giving the error. In any case the error message is clear: "Duplicate id 0x7f09012d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff"

Comment: i am not able to get it , new to android

Comment: Which line is DashboardFragment.kt:1183? (Side note: you really should not have a class with 1200 LoC, especially a fragment).

Comment: dialog1?.setContentView(R.layout.punch_details_layout)

Comment: Can you post `punch_details_layout.xml` and state which is line 29?